# How To Enable Keyboard Navigation for Large Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a large Asp.net (some pages are Ajaxable but not all) which I want to activate keyboard navigation for it.

Some shortcut key chosen to do or call some methods & functions or visible and hide page elements. These shortcuts are more than 50 keys.

In addition users must be able to change any shortcut (at this time it is not necessary but it has to be done)

So how can I enable keyboard navigation for my application?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of helpers I wrote in jQuery for another project.
Maybe you can use some of it:

```
App = {
    doStuff : function() {
        // a custom action
    },
    attachKeyboard : function(map) {
        jQuery(document).bind('keydown', {map: map, scope: this}, this.keyNav);
    },
    detachKeyboard : function(map) {
        jQuery(document).unbind('keydown', this.keyNav);
    },
    keyNav : function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
        var map = e.data.map;
        var scope = e.data.scope;
        var keymap = {
            UP: 38,
            DOWN: 40,
            LEFT: 37,
            RIGHT: 39,
            RETURN: 13,
            ESCAPE: 27,
            BACKSPACE: 8
        };
        for( var i in map ) {
            var k = i.toUpperCase();
            if ( keymap[k] ) {
                map[keymap[k]] = map[i];
            }
        }
        if (typeof map[key] == 'function') {
            map[key].apply(scope);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
App.attachKeyboard({
    up: this.doStuff,
    down: function() {
        // some other action
    },
    16: function() {
        // do stuff when charcode 16 is pressed
    }
});
```

If you want to change actions, you can just unbind the keyboard and re-bind it:

```
App.detachKeyboard();
App.attachKeyboard({
    up: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```